# Remove <VirtualEarth> tags from Bing API IRouteService Response

Tags: c#, regex, bing-api

I cant seem to find what has changed with the latest bing API update.  I haven't updated my app in a while, and my once before regular expression is no longer stripping the  tags from the IRouteService Response!

```
//Remove all Bing Maps tags around keywords.  
Regex regex = new Regex("<[/a-zA-Z:]*>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
textBlock1.Text = regex.Replace(directions.ToString(), string.Empty);
```

Unexpected Results:

```
Leg #1
1. 15.034  Head <VirtualEarth:span class="heading">northeast</VirtualEarth:span>. 
2. 8.4  Turn <VirtualEarth:TurnDir>left</VirtualEarth:TurnDir> 
3. 0  You will reach your destination . The destination is on your left.
```

Expected Results

```
Leg #1
1. 15.034  Head northeast. 
2. 8.4  Turn left 
3. 0  You will reach your destination . The destination is on your left.
```

Was wondering if something obvious is sticking out to you guys! Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `"`, , and `=` characters from your character class - they are part of the attributes on the tag.  Use this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("<[/a-zA-Z:\"' =]+>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

**Edit:** My first post included the `'` character that I used to test with instead of the `"` character - I've updated the code.

Comment: Probably best to include both `'` and `"`.  I've seen XML come back both ways, although `"` is the standard.

Comment: @Bobson: agreed!  :)  Added it back in.

Comment: Thanks Michael Bray and Bobson, this fixed me up perfectly :)